# Querying Mongodb for user information

Tags: node.js

I have users information in a Mongodb database. I want to be able to group users display based on if they are executive members or members or members on probation and i want to be able to display the 3 groups on the same page. How do i make the query?

```
<select class="form-control"name="currentOffice">
                                        <option>President</option>
                                        <option>Vice President</option>
                                        <option>Secretary General</option>
                                        <option>Assistant Secretary</option>
                                        <option>Financial Secretary</option>
                                        <option>Treasurer</option>
                                        <option>Welfare Officer I</option>
                                        <option>Welfare Officer II</option>
                                        <option>P.R.O.</option>
                                        <option>Provost</option>
                                        <option>Member</option>
                                        <option>Member on probation</option>
                                    </select>
```

I want the final display to look like: "Executive members", "Members" and "Members on probation"...
I may not have described this question in the best possible way, thank you.

Comment: what are the mongodb fields? HTML is not a good way to present this.

Comment: Not sure, are you asking for the User Schema?

Comment: yes, the schema in the db